# Laravel 5 css,js and image files are not loading

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am trying to load css, js and images files kept inside my public/css/assests folder. Link which i have been giving is

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/assets/js/jquery-ui/css/no-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css">
```

But when i open my page in browser it gives error that is

```
 GET http://localhost:8000/public/css/assets/js/jquery-ui/css/no-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Please tell me what to do to resolve the error.

Answer (score 5):

you can use `asset()` to load css and js and images from public folders.asset will point to public folder

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/assets/js/jquery-ui/css/no-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css')}}">
```

**asset()**

asset() will generate a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS):

Answer (score 1):

please use asset() function

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset('css/assets/js/jquery-ui/css/no-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css'); ?>">
```

asset() gives full url of your root directory

Answer (score 0):

`/` points to public folder by default, so remove `/public`

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/assets/js/jquery-ui/css/no-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css">
```